# Disable an outputPanel

Tags: visualforce, javascript, css, event

Is there a way to disable an `<apex:outputPanel>` ?

I have an `<apex:selectList>` and on the `onchange` event I want to disable the panel.

I tried :

```
style= "disabled: true;"
```

But it doesn't wordk.

Comment: I don't want to hide it, but only disable it's content !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't disable an outputPanel, but if your doctype is HTML5, you can disable a fieldset with the new "disabled" attribute. Like this:

```
<apex:outputPanel>
  <fieldset disabled="disabled">
    <!-- [FORM ELEMENTS] -->
  </fieldset>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

All input controls inside the fieldset will render as disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery:

```
$("select").prop('disabled', true);
```

or

```
$("{!$Component.mySelect}").prop('disabled', true);
```

(good discussion about some of the finer points of this in jQuery [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/how-to-disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery).)

or natively

```
document.getElementById("{!$Component.mySelect}").disabled = true;
```

I *think* there are some browser limitations on certain controls being disable-able, but can't recall for sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!onchangevalue}">
```

when onchange event happens In Controller just make onchangevalue to false
`onchangevalue = false` ;
it automatically disabled

Comment: Like I said above, I don't want to hide the panel, only disable the fields inside.